# Vue Router как передать переменныю c контроллера

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, laravel-5.7

Доброго времени суток.

Хочу передать переменные в с метода контроллера в представление .т.е

в контроллере собирается массив и передается :

```
  return view('estate.index', ["status" => $estate_status, "type" => $estate_types]);
```

в estate/index.blade.php

```
<router-view
                    :to="{
                    name: 'EstateIndex',
                     params: {
                     status:  status ,
                     type:  type,
                     created_by : created_by ,
                     deal : deal
                        }
                     }"
                ></router-view>
```

в app.js

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/estate',
            name: "EstateIndex",
            component: EstateIndex,
            props:true
        },
```

а template props добавлены

```
   export default {

        props:[
            'deal',
            'type',
            ...
        ],
```

но не работает ( в чем тут может быть ошибка ?

Ps : eсли указать в index.blade.php следующим образом - все работает ( но это не vue-router )

```
    <table-component :status="{{ json_encode($status) }}"
                         :type="{{ json_encode($type) }}"
                         :created_by="{{ json_encode($created_by) }}"
                         :deal="{{ json_encode($deal) }}"> </table-component>
```

Заранее спасибо )

Есть еще один путь решения - передавать данные в глобальных переменных ) 
Глобальные переменные - возможно это плохо - но т.к. в них содержаться только пункты меню - пока не парюсь по этому..)

а от и решение :
в index.blade.php задаем переменные полученные с контроллера

```
 <router-view></router-view>
...
    <script>
            window.status_new = {!!  json_encode($status_new) !!}
            window.type = {!! json_encode($type)!!}
            window.created_by = {!! json_encode($created_by)!!}
            window.deal ={!! json_encode($deal)!!}
    </script>
```

в компоненте принимаем

```
export default {
        data:() => ({
            deal: window.deal,
            type: window.type ,
            created_by: window.created_by ,
            status_new:window.status_new
...
```

Ps: пришлось переименовать переменную status - т.к. в ней содержалась строка ввида

> [{Object object}, {Object object}, {Object object}]

...хотя blade отдавал массив- непонятно (

Comment: Загрузите переменные с сервера через аях в каком-нибудь before-mount

Answer (score 0):

Логично, что vuejs ничего не знает про status, type, которые подсовываем ему laravel. У них разный порядок в жизненном цикле. Потому что когда php генерирует страницу еще до пока js код исполнится т.к. JS работать на стороне браузера. Собственно у вас и получается что laravel воспринимает status и type как строки. Во втором варианте у вас все получилось, потому что вы сразу вставили status как переменную используя специальный синтаксис.

Поэтому по аналогии нужно было сделать:

```
<router-view
    :to="{
    name: 'EstateIndex',
     params: {
     status: {!! json_encode($status) !!},
     type: {!! json_encode($type) !!},
     created_by : created_by ,
     deal : deal
        }
     }"
></router-view>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ ..  - но у меня это так и не заработало (
.. не понимаю в чем причина .. 
Пока нашел решение в использовании глобальных переменных (
Знаю , что это не есть хорошо .. пока не совсем понимаю чем плохо..

Вопрос дополню найденным решением ..

Comment: Status и type это объекты? Если да, то вам нужно обернуть вставку в json_encode.

Comment: это все массивы .. выше описал , что получилось

Comment: Давно не работал с laravel, но ваш идея с глобальными переменными делает то же самое, только в моем случае они не нужны. Судя по всему я использовал не правильный синтаксис. Надо было написать в точности как у вас было при передаче напрямую в компонент.

Answer (score 0):

php:

```
$this->template->render('member/list', ['params' =>  Json::encode($games)])
```

twig:

```
<router-view name ='member' :params={{params}} ></router-view>
```

routes.js:

```
  {
    path: '/member/list/:type',
    props: { default: true, member: true },
    components: {
      member: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "js/member/list" */ '~pages/member/list'),
      right: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "js/right/list" */ '~pages/member/right/list')
    }
  }
```

js/member/list.vue

```
export default {
  props: ['params', 'type']
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]